# Tableau Insert PDF into Dashboard

Tags: pdf, tableau-api

Is it possible to insert a PDF into a dashboard?  I have five PDF's I want to be hidden into text so that when you click the text, it can either open in Tableau (if possible) or open as a new web tab.  I looked around and couldn't find a method that did this.  Its for a title page of a dashboard with 5 class years that each need a separate PDF report attached to them.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible either by URL Action (to open in a new tab) or Web Page object on a dashboard. See this article for details of both options: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_dashboards.htm

Note I'm assuming your PDF is on a network drive / web page so is callable via URL.

Comment: I'll give that a try and get back to you.  I wanted to just put in the PDF so it wasn't a URL based connection (so that we don't have to upload the PDF somewhere on our website to link to) but we do have it on SharePoint and network drives so we can maybe work your method you linked to make it work.  I guess I am a little surprised that a PDF or hyperlinking text isn't an option in Tableau.

Comment: Following up, that link helped a bit for displaying web page entirely but I found this site to do the typical blue text and opens a new internet tab to a web link.  This was useful for doing a list of 5 clickable links but now the new challenge is finding a way to hyperlink text in a paragraph.

https://www.thedataschool.co.uk/tom-pilgrem/how-to-add-hyperlinks-to-your-dashboards/